# UIView.animate not animating my UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIVisualEffectView created in IB and a property

```
@IBOutlet weak var visualEffectStack: UIVisualEffectView!
```

I can show and hide the visual effect view using

```
visualEffectStack.isHidden = false
visualEffectStack.isHidden = true
```

or using alpha.

I want to animate appearance of the view, but it does not animate.

```
visualEffectStack.alpha = 0
visualEffectStack.isHidden = false

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [.curveEaseIn, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
        self.visualEffectStack.alpha = 1
    })
```

Is there a problem in my code or is it the visual effect view?

Swift 3.1 and iOS 10

Comment: try opacity instead of alpha

Comment: Just tested your code its working as expected.What you mean `not animating`. you should considered changing your `animation duration` to higher value(`duration` or `delay` 0.5 is too quick if you using above code in viewDidLoad).

Comment: @Joe Thanks for testing it out. When I create simple project with nothing else, it also works for me. I am adding details (custom views, rounded corners etc.) to get closer to the real world project and trying to find what is causing this.

Comment: @MirekE where are you calling your animation?

Comment: @TusharSharma On a button click.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research I found that the `UIVisualEffectView` should be always kept with alpha = 1. So animating `alpha` or `isHidden` should never be done.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivisualeffectview):

> **Setting the Correct Alpha Value**
>
> When using the UIVisualEffectView class, avoid alpha values that are less than 1. Creating views that
>   are partially transparent causes the system to combine the view and
>   all the associated subviews during an offscreen render pass.
>   UIVisualEffectView objects need to be combined as part of the content
>   they are layered on top of in order to look correct. Setting the alpha
>   to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews
>   causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all.